# Adding a yellow row vba code in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the code below to insert and entire yellow row after a date change in my spreadsheet and it is working great however, I would now like to actually add the DAY in the yellow high-lighed row in column A corresponding with the date change. I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

```
   Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("L7:L500")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'

If iRow = 500 Then
    End
ElseIf Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = "" Then
    iRow = iRow + 1
ElseIf Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).Text = "" Then
    If Left(Cells(iRow + 2, iCol), 14) <> Left(Cells(iRow, iCol), 14) Then
        Cells(iRow + 2, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        Range(Cells(iRow + 2, 1), Cells(iRow + 2, 22)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
'        Rows(iRow + 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        iRow = iRow + 3
    Else
        iRow = iRow + 2
    End If
ElseIf Left(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), 14) <> Left(Cells(iRow, iCol), 14) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    Range(Cells(iRow + 1, 1), Cells(iRow + 1, 22)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
'    Rows(iRow + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfect thank you J.Reid !

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after inserting your row

```
Range(Cells(iRow + 1, 1), Cells(iRow + 1, iCol)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Where the first Cell is the start of the Row and the Second Cell is the end of the row. If you want the entire row then do this

```
Rows(iRow + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Comment: J.Reid I have an additional question after I add a yellow line to separate data based on a date change as reflected above, now I would like to add the "Day" corresponding with the inserted yellow line in column A. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are saying 'Day' as in Thursday or 03 (11/03/2016). I don't quite follow what you mean by Day. Also without an example data set this is quite vague. If the date change was from 11/01/2016 to 11/03/2016 what value do you want in Column A?